# Labels displaying slightly below form checkbox?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I want my text to display inline with my form checkbox - and as far as I know, this is the appropriate code. For some reason, the text is falling slightly beneath the check box? See screen shot and code below.

[image]

**style.css**

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;

}

input {

   height: 35px;
   width: 325px;
   font-size: 16px;
}

input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {

    width: 30px;

}
    label {

        font-size: 18px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: lighter;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

        label[for=receive_newsletters] {

            font-size: 12px;
            display: inline-block;

        }

        label[for=terms_accepted] {

            font-size: 12px;
            display: inline-block;

        }
```

**new.html.erb**

```
    <label for="receive_newsletters"><%= f.check_box :receive_newsletters %> I would like to receive newsletters</label>
    <label for="terms_accepted"><%= f.check_box :terms_accepted %> I agree to the Terms of Service & Privacy Policy</label>

    <%= f.submit :Register %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: @Vucko Tried it - no dice :/

Comment: Can you post all your styles?

Comment: @Vucko See above. Added all of my form related styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `height: 35px;` from `input` or specify `height: auto` for `input[type=checkbox]`